# Form data upload from iPhone to PHP server via https

Tags: php, iphone, https

Is there a good tutorial or sample project of how to upload data from iPhone to a self-owned web server? The project is like:

- A survey application on iPhone which stores the user input data in a plist
- When there is internet connection, the program will enable an "Upload" button
- When the Upload button is clicked, the program will upload the data via HTTP form submit (POST)
- The server is Linux + MySQL + Apache + PHP
- The data should be sent via a `https://` connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of tutorials around, however, to send form data, I gave up with "tinkering" and used the open source ASIHTTPRequest library (in fact ASIHTTPFormRequest) its fantastic and makes it all pretty trivial. http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ The download includes examples